# Piping http.Response to http.ResponseWriter

Tags: go

I'm trying to pipe a file that I receive from an API back to the user without having to store it all in memory.

I've come across different concepts/ideas across my search, such as `io.Copy`, `io.Pipe()`, etc. I'm not sure which one is the correct solution.

For example, `io.Pipe()` seems like it's for if someone is creating a new reader and writer on the spot, not ones that already exist.

Answer (score 21):

[`io.Copy`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy) is the way to go for that, something along the lines of:

```
func pipeReq(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    resp, err := http.Get(".....")
    if err != nil{
        //handle the error
        return
    }
    rw.Header().Set("Content-Type", resp.Header.Get("Content-Type"))
    rw.Header().Set("Content-Length", resp.Header.Get("Content-Length"))
    io.Copy(rw, resp.Body)
    resp.Body.Close()

}
```

//edit: misread the question, fixed the code now.

Answer (score 0):

@OneOfOne's answer is great but one small improvement is to use [`io.CopyBuffer`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#CopyBuffer). CopyBuffer is identical to Copy except that it stages through the provided buffer (if one is required) rather than allocating a temporary one

```
func pipeReq(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    resp, err := http.Get(".....")
    if err != nil{
        //handle the error
        return
    }
    rw.Header().Set("Content-Type", resp.Header.Get("Content-Type"))
    rw.Header().Set("Content-Length", resp.Header.Get("Content-Length"))  
    buf := make([]byte, 8)
    if _, err := io.CopyBuffer(rw, resp.Body, buf); err != nil {
        // handle the error
        return
    }
    resp.Body.Close()   
}
```